# Снятие данных с инерциальных датчиков во время захвата изображения с камеры

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Суть задачи - во время захвата изображения снять данные с инерциальных датчиков (акселерометр и гироскоп), которые будут, в дальнейшем, использоваться для обработки изображения. Пользуясь уроками и статьями написал программку, и испытываю трудности с корректным снятием показаний с датчиков. Конкретнее - **во время захвата изображения с камеры,** у меня выходит снять какие то данные с акселерометра (приходится что-то около 30 показаний на один снимок), однако **с гироскопа снять данные не удаётся**, хотя методы снятия идентичны. В дебаге с гироскопа какие то данные таки снимаются, пусть и единожды.
Сам код - по нажатию на кнопку вызывается следующий метод:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private void takePicture() {
        if (mCameraDevice == null)
            return;

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (cameraCharacteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = cameraCharacteristics.get(cameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                        .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }

            //Capture image with custom size
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if ((jpegSizes != null) && (jpegSizes.length > 0)) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurface.add(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, mExposure); //Смена выдержки

            //Check orientation base on device
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORRIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");

            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            final String fileName = currentTime.toString();

            mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    mPhotoDirectoryName
                            + File.separator
                            + fileName
                            + ".jpg");

            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        mGyroscopeSensorActivity.turnOffSensors();
                        mAccelerometerSensorActivity.turnOffSensors();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (image != null)
                            image.close();
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try {
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);

                        new SingleMediaScanner(mContext, mFile);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (outputStream != null)
                            outputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            };

            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureStarted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                    super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                    mGyroscopeSensorActivity.turnOnSensors();
                    mAccelerometerSensorActivity.turnOnSensors();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureFailure failure) {
                    super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
                    mGyroscopeSensorActivity.turnOffSensors();
                    mAccelerometerSensorActivity.turnOffSensors();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
                    super.onCaptureProgressed(session, request, partialResult);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    ///mGyroscopeSensorActivity.turnOffSensors();
                    ///mAccelerometerSensorActivity.turnOffSensors();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved " + mFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    preparationForCalculations();

                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    try {
                        cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

В onCaptureStarted вызываю

```
public class GyroscopeSensorActivity extends Activity implements 
SensorEventListener {
    ...
    public void turnOnSensors() {
        clearBuff();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, maxReportLatencyNs);
    }
    ...
}
```

и аналогичный метод из класса под акселерометр (пока разбил оба сенсора на разные классы), с целью очистки буферов для данных и начала прослушки сенсоров. Сохраняю показания с датчиков

```
public class GyroscopeSensorActivity extends Activity implements 
SensorEventListener {
    ...
    private List<Float> mCommonAnglesGyro;
    private List<List<Float>> mGyroData;

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mCommonAnglesGyro.size(); i++) {
            mCommonAnglesGyro.set(i, event.values[i]);
        }
        mGyroData.add(mCommonAnglesGyro);
    }
    ...
}
```

и, по срабатыванию onImageAvailable (когда никакой полезной, как я понял, информации с сенсоров, относящихся к захваченному изображению больше не получить) в методе MainActivity.takePicture, вызываю

```
public class GyroscopeSensorActivity extends Activity implements 
SensorEventListener {
    ...
    public void turnOffSensors() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

останавливая прослушку сенсоров.
Собственно, снятие данных с гироскопа не работает, впрочем в акселерометре я также не уверен, как можно поправить данную ситуацию?
Также, являясь новичком в java, не откажусь от любых замечаний.